# How to say "is that it?" and "come here" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, conjugación

How do you say "Is that it?" in Spanish? Is "¿Es que él?" right?

Also, how do you say "Come here" to two people in the informal tense? I only know of ustedes, but that's formal tense.

Comment: I'm intrigued why you wrote ¿es que Él? Where did you get that from? Yourself or by using a translator?

Comment: You should add a bit more context for your question, such as some examples where you would use those expressions.

Answer (score 1):

He aquí algunos ejemplos traducidos de la expresión **Is that it?**:

> *¿Eso es? / ¿es eso? / ¿eso es todo?*

Ejemplos para la expresión **Come here**:

> (to one person/informal) = *Ven aquí*
>
> (to one person/formal) = *Venga aquí*
>
> (to two people/informal) = *Venid aquí*
>
> (to two people/formal) = *Vengan aquí*

Answer (score 0):

For "Is that it?":

- ¿Eso es todo? / ¿Listo? / ¿(Eso) sería todo?

For "Come here":

- Ven aquí (most common in Latin America).

Comment: Hola mario y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Gracias por tu respuesta. Nótese, sin embargo, que es bastante limitada: ¿podrías [edit]arla para incluir más detalles que puedan ayudar a quien formuló la pregunta? Te puede ser de interés leer [answer].